# Exporting Cloud Messaging to BigQuery doesn't work

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-cloud-messaging

On Google Firebase I enabled BigQuery and selected Cloud Messaging. firebase_messaging dataset was automatically created on the BigQuery and more than 48 hours have passed but no table has been created although we are firebase is sending notifications as per attached screenshot.

I checked under the transfer section of BigQuery and I noticed the following error as per the attached screenshot: source data not found. I tried backfilling the data but I get the same error. Do you know what could cause this error?

The developers have not yet inserted the code on the apps to be able to collect information on the delivery of notifications. But from the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery?authuser=1&hl=it&platform=ios#how_does_this_data_differ_from_data_exported_to_bigquery we read that BigQuery export also provides single message logs about message acceptance by the FCM backend. So we expected activating BigQuery to collect this data, maybe it doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is your problem, but encountered a vexing issue when inspecting the table called "data" under firebase_messaging in Big Query Explorer. When I ran the query, I couldn't see any data at all. The query looked like:

```
SELECT * FROM `my-app-name.firebase_messaging.data` WHERE TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(_PARTITIONTIME, DAY) = TIMESTAMP("2023-07-06") LIMIT 1000
```

This was the default query so I assumed that it would be good, but running it produced zero rows of results. I have tried it for several days, and still nothing. Today I checked the Preview tab and found that there was actually something to preview. Finally, I realised that the one day partition set by default is not suitable for viewing Firebase data that only gets synced 24 hours after it's produced. Therefore, I set the timestamp to be several days earlier and now I see results. In other words setting `TIMESTAMP("2023-07-01")` produces results. A quick and dirty query without any timestamp restriction is:

```
SELECT * FROM `my-app-name.firebase_messaging.data` DESC LIMIT 1000
```

Now I can actually see the notification delivery information.

Comment: Same experience here. However I don't see any "recent" results, like registration of messages I did over the last couple of hours from a device. They don't show up in the data. The newest data available is some day old or so. Is there a huge (well 24 hours?) time lag in place somewhere?

Comment: BTW I found this comment in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery?platform=ios#bigquery-data-export): "Firebase sets up regular syncs of your data from your Firebase project to BigQuery. These daily export operations begin at 4:00 AM Pacific Time and usually finish in 24 hours.". This should mean logs from Firebase only sync to BigQuery once a 24-hour day.